# How to resize/resample bitmap images within pdfs and maintain vector overlays

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, vector-graphics, inkscape, resampling

My workflow is usually as follows:

I annotate bitmap images using inkscape with vector elements (text, lines, etc.). I export a pdf from inkscape and include it in my pdflatex source (includegraphics...).

Somehow, I don't want to downscale the bitmaps prior to embedding in inkscape to keep the svg files universal. On the other hand, the resulting pdfs after pdflatex are often unnecessary huge due to the images in full (ridiculous) resolution. Unfortunately, the pdf export of inkscape does not support a downsampling of bitmaps right away (this is, however, often discussed). So I tried to use ghostscript to reduce the pdfs from inkscape before running pdflatex. However, all my vector annotations are rendered in this process which is what I want to avoid and what this question is about.

I used ghostscript like this (found this in different flavors but nothing worked):

```
gs  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 \
-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
-dEmbedAllFonts=true \
-dSubsetFonts=true \
-dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
-dColorImageResolution=200 \
-dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
-dGrayImageResolution=400 \
-dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
-dMonoImageResolution=1200 \
-sOutputFile=out.pdf \
 in.pdf
```

So I am looking for some help/ideas to get my image pdfs smaller yet still with the vector art in vector format.

Answer (score 4):

1) Don't use -dPDFSETTINGS unless you are *very* sure what it will do. In your cas,e really don't use it.

2) 200 ,400 and 1200 (!) dpi are still very high resolutions, you could try still lower.

3) You haven't set -dDownsampleColorImages, -dDownsampleGrayImages or -dDownsampleMonoImages. So the changes to the downsampling type and resolution won't actually do anything. (I know this is ridiculous, blame Adobe for the settings which we have to mimic....)

If you can supply an example file I can test this, but my suspicion is that '3' is your problem. You might also want to look at the ColorImageDownsampleThreshold (and Gray/Mono) switch.